# Restarting LDAP client service

Tags: solaris, ldap, openldap

I have modified `ldap.conf` and `slapd.conf`. I'm wondering how I can restart the  ldap/client service, filesystem/autofs and name-service/cache.

*OS: Solaris 11 but advice on linux should help too*

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @SoumyadipDM Solaris 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`svcadm restart ldap/client` should do the trick. Depending on what you're running you might also need to restart filesystem/autofs

Answer (score 2):

To find out the names(FMRI) of the SMF services, you can use `svcs -a | grep service_name` e.g `svcs -a | grep ldap`

Once you know the name of the SMF service name, you can use following to restart that
`svcadm restart ldap`

Then you can check the status of the service using `svcs ldap`

A good guide on SMF can be found here 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/intro-smf-basics-s11-1729181.html